# OwnCloud 8.x update on my Pi got stuck!

Tags: update, owncloud

I 2 days back tried to update the OwnCloud 7.x on my pi to 8.x when I saw the message on the owncloud interface. I tried the updater tool and it failed. So I ran `sudo apt-get install owncloud` and it downloaded the owncloud tar and placed it properly. I followed the instructions here: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/maintenance/upgrade.html

Why I said 'properly' is that when I opened owncloud using my browser, I saw that the owncloud installation was ready for update. I clicked on update and it ran forever.
[image]

Now the service is stopped and I cannot connect to owncloud.

Any pointer for help?

Comment: Take a look at the logfile - if it crashed or had an error it is very likely that it tells you where the problem is...
On my PI it is located at `/var/www/owncloud/data/owncloud.log`

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve it by using the command line updater OCC. I have used

```
sudo -u www-data php occ upgrade
```

as in described [here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/maintenance/upgrade.html).

---

<sup>Answer was provided by OP as edit to question.</sup>